# .htaccess or .htpasswd equivalent on IIS?

Tags: iis, .htaccess

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent to .htaccess and .htpassword for IIS ? I am being asked to migrate an app to IIS that uses .htaccess to control access to sets of files in various URLs based on the contents of .htaccess files.

I did a google search and didn't turn up anything conclusive. Is there a general approach or tool that I need to purchase that provides this capability ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For .htaccess rewrite:
  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Or try aping .htaccess:
  http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a direct 1:1 equivalent.

You can password protect a folder or file using file system permissions.  If you are using ASP.Net you can also use some of its built in functions to protect various urls.

If you are trying to port .htaccess files used for url rewriting, check out ISAPI Rewrite: http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it but [Trilead](http://www.trilead.com/Products/Trilead_ISAPI_Filter_for_IIS/), a free ISAPI filter which enables .htaccess based control, looks like what you want.

Comment: Sadly that one is no longer supported

Comment: sorry. this used to be the right answer but trilead seems to be gone. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is the documentation that you want:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114(VS.71).aspx

I guess the answer is, yes, there is an equivalent that will accomplish the same thing, integrated with Windows security.

Comment: Although IIS does support basic authentication, it (apparently) requires a local (or domain) accounts. This means you cannot carry over a htpasswd file, since you cannot convert the passwords.