# is there something like htaccess for windows asp.net/IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, iis

is there something like htaccess in the windows iis server?

dont like to use Forms or something

Comment: This should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this SO post:

[.htaccess or .htpasswd equivalent on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257936/htaccess-or-htpasswd-equivalent-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

The web.config file is similar. But it depends on what you want to do with it.