# Is it possible to have a simple user-password authentication without having a login form?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm searching for this, but I can't find it, yet I know that this can be done with an htaccess file, since this is what the screenshot below does.

I want to secure a folder behind a preset username and password. I can't create a Windows user since I do not own the server and we don't need an authentication form. We want to use the default authentication form of the browser.

How is this possible from the web.config?

This i what I have but it does not work

```
<system.web>    
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        <user name="test" password="test" />
      </credentials>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="test" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

[image: Google Chrome asking for a username and password]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with forms authentication.

There seems to be a third party library to use htaccess/htpasswd style directory access configuration on IIS:

http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

See also [.htaccess or .htpasswd equivalent on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257936/htaccess-or-htpasswd-equivalent-on-iis)

Comment: A 3rd library would force me to install something on the IIS server, which I do not control. I was looking for a web.config only solution. Guess it can't be done, and that explain why I can't find anything.

Comment: It looks like you can deploy it with your web site: `/bin` directory, `web.config` and `/Helicon/httpd.conf` are only modified according to their manual installation instructions: http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/minstall.htm