# Can not run php application on iis

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I have a php application which runs on apache webserver very well.
I did not use any php framework. I did everything myself.

But now I have a Big problem.
We want to run this application on IIS.(Not an Apache).
And when I try to run in my local IIS server, it does nothing.

I have installed php for iis from ms web platform..

I think problem is in **web.config** file.

There is a  url rewriting in .htaccess file, it runs very well.
But when I translated it to web.config there is a problem.
Browser show nothing, only the message

**"The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request."**

Below is my .htacces and web.config files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Hide Index" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So what is the problem?
Could you help Me, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess or .htpasswd equivalent on IIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257936/htaccess-or-htpasswd-equivalent-on-iis)

Comment: do you have to us iis? can't you use xampp ? as above iis and .htaccess aren't compatible.

Comment: unfortunately, yes I have to use iis...