# .htaccess on ISS Webserver

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, typo3

I made a TYPO3 Webpage and use the RealURL which is saved in the .htaccess.

Now I want to make this Homepage working on a IIS Webserver and have the problem that the .htaccess does not work properly, because IIS uses the web.config file.

Can anybody tell me what i have to do, so that I can use all the code of the .htaccess file?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Simple google search:

[.htaccess or .htpasswd equivalent on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257936/htaccess-or-htpasswd-equivalent-on-iis)

https://superuser.com/questions/800261/using-htaccess-with-iis

https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig