# RewriteCond can't find file if has accent in it

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It redirects everything to index.php if it's not a file or a directory. It works fine, but when a file has an accent in its name it redirects the url to index.php, so the RewriteCond can't detect that it's an existing file. For example (both files exist):

This works: http://example.com/something.pdf (gives me the PDF)

But this doesn't: [http://example.com/somethingá.pdf](http://example.com/something%C3%A1.pdf) (redirects me to index.php)

The problem is that I don't have access to the web server conf, since it is on a webhosting server.

The system is Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Server Edition Service Pack 1 (by PhpInfo)

Web server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Comment: Apache version? Works fine for me using XAMMP (Apache 2.4.3) on a Win7 dev box.

Comment: @CD001 Edited my post, but it's Microsoft-IIS/7.5.

Comment: That's your problem them, `.htaccess`, `mod_rewrite` and so on are Apache specific - IIS uses a *Web.config* XML file I believe.

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257936/htaccess-or-htpasswd-equivalent-on-iis

Comment: @CD001 Based on the information you've provided I can fix it converting the .htaccess file to a web.config file. Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on CD001's comment, I've found out that however IIS can convert .htacess files automatically, but doesn't work 100% all the time. So I fixed the problem by converting the `.htaccess` file to a `web.config` file manually. The converted file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule 1">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Save it as `web.config` in the root of your webpage to get it work and delete the `.htacess`.