# Codeigniter remove index.php does not work

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

im using iis server, i tried some ways but it did not work;

config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess;

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

why the index.php does not remove from url? how i can remove it in another way?

Comment: Try adding a `?` question mark in your rule in the last line. Eg - `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: Can you first check mod_rewrite is enabled or not

Comment: what? what do u mean? adding a which part?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127805/i-can-not-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter-in-iis-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Refer this. This is the previous loop that have already raised the same question

Comment: yes it works but all url remove when i use it, "500 http error"

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /yourfoler/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|install|update) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For godady Shared Hosting Server uncomment the line below
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Please comment this if you have uncommented the above
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

re write Htaacess

Comment: bro i tried but it does not work, here an example link; http://88.248.31.106/projeler/10012/index.php

Comment: i copied and paste ur codes as delete n create new file but still give error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, Please remove all the code from .htaccess and check below, I am not sure, I think it's work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|install|update)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It comes from Laravel, but has always worked for me with CodeIgniter aswell.